# How to remove the matched elements from the given array of strings using jolt?

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

Input Json:

```
{
  "dynamicArray1" : [ "A", "C", "E", "J" ],
  "dynamicArray2" : [ "A", "B", "C" ,"L"]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{

"unmatchedElements"  : ["B","L"]

}
```

I receive two dynamic String arrays, as shown above, then need to match the values of dynamicArray1 in dynamicArray2 and remove the matched elements from dynamicArray2, and finally should give the unmatched elements of dynamicArray2 in the output array as shown above.

Comment: @mattyb Is it possible to achieve this using jolt?

Answer (score 0):

While not a Jolt, this could be done with ScriptedTransformRecord. The benefit being you would not need to split the JSON in to unique FlowFiles.

[ScriptedTransformRecord docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ScriptedTransformRecord/index.html)

[ScriptedTransformRecord examples](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ScriptedTransformRecord/additionalDetails.html)

[image: ScriptedRecordTransform Flow]
[image: ScriptedRecordTransform Config]

Python:

```
a = record.getValue("dynamicArray1")
b = record.getValue("dynamicArray2")
diff = list(set(b).difference(a))
record.setValue("unmatchedElements",diff)
_ = record
```

Output:

```
[ {
  "dynamicArray1" : [ "A", "C", "E", "J" ],
  "dynamicArray2" : [ "A", "B", "C", "L" ],
  "unmatchedElements" : [ "B", "L" ]
} ]
```

Then remove the fields you don't need (you could achieve that by setting the JSONRecordSetWriter schema to only have the `unmatchedElements` field, which will drop the other fields).

Flow JSON here https://pastebin.com/2z7JuQ1G